# Why when launch without delay (in Android), it didn't finish the task?

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have a simple coroutine experiment below

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        runBlocking {
            launch {
                repeat(5) {
                    Log.d("Track", "First, current thread: ${Thread.currentThread()}'")
                    delay(1)
                }
            }

            launch {
                repeat(5) {
                    Log.d("Track", "Second, current thread: ${Thread.currentThread()}'")
                    delay(1)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This prints all 5 times, alternatively for both the `launch`.

```
Track: First, current thread: Thread[main @coroutine#2,5,main]'
Track: Second, current thread: Thread[main @coroutine#3,5,main]'
Track: First, current thread: Thread[main @coroutine#2,5,main]'
Track: Second, current thread: Thread[main @coroutine#3,5,main]'
Track: First, current thread: Thread[main @coroutine#2,5,main]'
Track: Second, current thread: Thread[main @coroutine#3,5,main]'
Track: First, current thread: Thread[main @coroutine#2,5,main]'
Track: Second, current thread: Thread[main @coroutine#3,5,main]'
Track: First, current thread: Thread[main @coroutine#2,5,main]'
Track: Second, current thread: Thread[main @coroutine#3,5,main]'
```

However, if I remove the `delay(1)` from the code for both `launch`

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        runBlocking {
            launch {
                repeat(5) {
                    Log.d("Track", "First, current thread: ${Thread.currentThread()}'")
                    // delay(1)
                }
            }

            launch {
                repeat(5) {
                    Log.d("Track", "Second, current thread: ${Thread.currentThread()}'")
                    // delay(1)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

It only prints 2 times and in sequence for both `launch`.

```
Track: First, current thread: Thread[main @coroutine#2,5,main]'
Track: First, current thread: Thread[main @coroutine#2,5,main]'
Track: Second, current thread: Thread[main @coroutine#3,5,main]'
Track: Second, current thread: Thread[main @coroutine#3,5,main]'
```

Why didn't it finish all the 5 times loop?

**Notes** It works fine when running this in Unit Test (non Android environment, i.e. all 5 times got printed)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Android's logger omits duplicate log messages after it sees more than two consecutive, identical messages, declaring the package to be "chatty".

Try this without coroutines, and you'll see:

```
    repeat(10) {
        Log.d("all the same", "Hello World")
    }
    repeat(10) {
        Log.d("with indices", "Hello World $it")
    }
```

The delay in your code prevents the identical messages from being consecutive, since you have two coroutines logging at once.